# How to make background image in mobile be fixed or static?

Tags: html, css

I cant seem to make the background in mobile to be fixed.
I tried the following:

```
.customBackground{ 
background-image:url('planwallpaper.com/static/images/3d-balls-hd-wallpaper.j‌​pg') !important; 
background-size:cover !important; 
background-repeat:no-repeat !important; 
background-attachment:fixed !important; 
}
```

Btw..i'm using a platform..called..dudaone.. its a multiscreen platform..what i want to know..is why the background-attachment:fixed !important; not working on mobile and tablets.
But it didn't help. 
What am I missing?

Comment: example please...

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where's your code?  See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what's happening in your code, so here's a general solution:

If you've set a background on your  element like:

```
body {
  background:url('../images/img.jpg');
}
```

You can then use a media query to set `background-attachment: fixed;` on your element only on a specific screen resolution (i.e. mobile) like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){
  body{
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
}
```

If you want to read more on media queries, you can check out [MDN's page on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

I hope this helps. If you could post your code it would make it easier for us to help, since we would be able to see exactly what's going on.